# turning off cache in a laravel project

Tags: laravel

I have bought a PHP script that is Laravel based, I'm ok with PHP but when I make changes they don't take effect on the site. I'm on PHP 7.4 and the script foundation is Laravel 8. I have tried all of the "solutions" on the web to no avail. I'm guessing it's a cache problem, if I deliberately make an error in the coding on the file and the go to the part of the site that calls it, the site falls over so it is looking at the file. The file is a controller.php file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Providing a [mcve] will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: If you provide your code it helps a lot but in general I don't think laravel cache has anything to do with controller's code.